# ES6 Symbols in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, ecmascript-harmony, ecmascript-6

I'm experimenting with the new ES6 Symbols in Google Chrome, and after enabling "Experimental JavaScript" in Chrome Flags, I can use `new Symbol()` in my code.

However, when I try to run the following code:

```
var sym = new Symbol();
var obj = {};
obj[sym] = 'Hello, symbols';
```

I get the following error:

`TypeError: Conversion from symbol to string`

What's wrong with my code?

Thanks!

Comment: Create symbol by calling `Symbol` as a function (`Symbol()`) not as constructor (`new Symbol()`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since symbols are values, not objects, they are created by a plain function call to `Symbol`, not by invoking `new` on it. In the version of Chrome you are using, `new Symbol` gives you a wrapper object for such a value (i.e., you can get the actual symbol by invoking `.valueOf` on the result).

Since this is a common pitfall, the ES6 draft spec recently changed to disallow constructor invocation of `Symbol` altogether. That is, you already get an exception on the first line of your code. This change has already been implemented in V8, but hasn't made it into Chrome yet.

Comment: Thanks, it works! I was confused by the fact that when I call `Symbol()` without invoking `new` on it, for some reason chrome console prints this value as `null`.

Comment: Yeah, I don't think anybody has done the work to teach Chrome devtools ES6 stuff yet.